# How to choose a particular frame/image from sprite sheet?-LibGdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I used to create animation like this.

```
private Animation handAnimation;    

handAnimation=new Animation(0.25f, playAtlas.createSprites(RegionNames.HAND_ANIMATION),Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
```

drawing like this:

```
handTexture = handAnimation.getKeyFrame(animationTime, true);
batch.draw(handTexture, Constants.WORLD_WIDTH - (2 * handTexture.getRegionWidth()),Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT / 4);
```

Here this animation has 4 frames.
Atlas file look like this:

```
hand.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Nearest,Nearest
repeat: none
hand
  rotate: false
  xy: 1, 1
  size: 102, 152
  orig: 102, 152
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 1
hand
  rotate: false
  xy: 105, 1
  size: 102, 152
  orig: 102, 152
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 2
hand
  rotate: false
  xy: 209, 1
  size: 102, 152
  orig: 102, 152
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 3
hand
  rotate: false
  xy: 313, 1
  size: 102, 152
  orig: 102, 152
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 4
```

Now I want to get a particular frame (third frame) of this sprite sheet for some other use.How can I get the third frame only?

One more thing I want to know,whether it is possible to change the order of the animation with such a sprite sheet?If so how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `playAtlas.createSprites("hand")`

For your case this will create 4 Spirtes and return into in `Array`. `Sprite` holds lots of data that you not required so it's only wastage of memory.

so use  `playAtlas.findRegions("hand")` instead of `playAtlas.createSprites("hand")`

```
handAnimation=new Animation(0.25f,playAtlas.findRegions("hand"), Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
```

`Animation` is now generic so declare in this way :

```
Animation<TextureRegion> handAnimation;
TextureRegion handTextureRegion;

handTextureRegion = handAnimation.getKeyFrame(animationTime, true);
```

---

1. You needed 3rd frame as `Sprite` or `TextureRegion` ?

   If as Sprite use `playAtlas.createSprite("hand",3);` or if as TextureRegion use `playAtlas.findRegions("hand").get(2);`
2. Yes you can change order of the animation, but before Animation object initialization. `findRegions()` of TextureAtlas return an Array, use element of that Array and create own Array according to own custom order and pass newly custom 
   Array as parameter in Animation constructor.

There is a protected method `setKeyFrames(T... keyFrames)` so only child of Animation can use to set new/custom KeyFrame.

Some of playback modes are available like `REVERSED`,`LOOP_PINGPONG`,`LOOP_RANDOM`, but all are in some order except `RANDOM`.

You can change mode of your animation any time you want by `animation.setPlayMode(PlayMode playMode);`

Comment: Look at his atlas file index number.     playAtlas.createSprite("hand",2); return 2nd sprite not 3rd.

Comment: Animation<TextureRegion> handAnimation; how this is possible?@Abhishek Aryan

Comment: @Niranjana From gdx version 1.9.5 `Animation` class is now generic, there is a [pull request](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/4448) for the same. I am sure you're using some older version.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the specific sprite from atlas

```
    createSprite(java.lang.String name, int index)
//Returns the first region found with the specified name and index as a sprite.
```

IN your code for third sprite :

```
playAtlas.createSprite("hand",3);
```

For Reverse animation try this :

```
handAnimation=new Animation(0.25f, playAtlas.createSprites(RegionNames.HAND_ANIMATION),Animation.PlayMode.LOOP_REVERSED);
```